# Adding local JS files to Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying to add some local js files available in my `assets/js` folder, but to no success.

The error I get is: `http://localhost:3001/assets/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Page not found: /assets/js/app.js)`

The way I try to do it is by adding it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
app: {
  head: {
    script: [
      {'src': 'assets/js/plugins.init.js', body: true},
      {'src': 'assets/js/app.js', body: true}
    ],
  },
},
```

and I tried adding it in the page as well:

```
useHead({
script: [
{
    src: `assets/js/app.js`,
    body: true,
    defer: true
},
{
    src: `assets/js/plugins.init.js`,
    body: true,
    defer: true
},
],
})
```

What am I doing wrong? and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your js file in `public` directory which we call `static` in nuxt2

**NOTE:** body property is deprecated instead you need to use `tagPosition`

See more [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta#body-tags)

In your `pages`

```js
useHead({
script: [
  {
    src: `/app.js`,
    tagPosition: 'bodyClose'
    defer: true
  },
 ],
})
```

In you `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
app: {
  head: {
    script: [
      {'src': '/plugins.init.js', tagPosition: 'bodyClose'},
      {'src': '/app.js', tagPosition: 'bodyClose'}
    ],
  },
},
```